# Photoshop "Save to Web" automation

Tags: javascript, automation, photoshop, cs4

I'm fairly new to Photoshop (Still CS4) and I often get designs for websites where slicing them up takes a fairly decent amount of time.
Some sites have layers that are all going to be the same exact size, and they are stacked on top of each other (Slideshows, that type of thing).

I usually move these layers to a new document with the size I need, display one at a time, and "Save for web" as 24-bit transparent (non-interlaced) PNGs.
Sometimes its only 5 images, other times its 10 times that. I don't mind getting paid to do this, but after a while it gets incredibly boring and I would like to automate it.

I have some basic JS experience with Adobe specific APIs from Illustrator, but no experience with Photoshop.

Comment: FWIW, any save for web stuff you do _will_ be recorded in an action (window > actions )

Comment: That isn't the type of answer I was looking for, but thanks for the comment and info

Comment: Ryan, what's the question that you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have PS on my machine here, but does the script under File -> Scripts -> Layer Comps to Files help?
You can create different layer comps and then files from them. I don't know about output formats though.

Edit: You can also make a copy of the Layer Comps to Files script and change it to call Save for Web.
See the [reference book](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop_cs4_javascript_ref.pdf).

Comment: Where is an answer here? It should be a comment.

Comment: Where have you been all my life, Layer Comps? This does the job, however it isn't much of a "Save to Web" item, its more like "Save As" and because of this, I cannot say this is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a sprite creation plugin of some sort.

If you were using Adobe Fireworks instead of Photoshop then that would allow you to set link, active, rollover states which would save all to a separate layers and allow you to design them separately but I'm not sure that's what you want. I could do with that capability myself.

I had a look and found:

http://gmurphey.com/blog/2011/07/07/photoshop-plugin-simple-sprites

http://www.garagegames.com/community/blogs/view/11527